# A Like "Sticky Notes" C# Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

I needed an idea for my last year's C# project and thought of creating a like Windows 7 "Sticky Notes" application, slightly improved.
I am an experienced C# developer, but I have not programmed for a while, and I don't know where to look for information on how to achieve this.

My idea is, that the application will run just like the original Windows 7 Sticky Notes, with some more options like configuring the font, adding reminders and such...

Where can I find information about how to create an application with a 'transparent' background, which will show the desktop while running (just like the Sticky Notes app)
and information about displaying messages from a system tray icon (like when your windows has updated ready to be installed)?

Thank you!

Comment: you can find these info downloading Windows 7 SDK and looking at examples and documentation included in such SDK; then you can ask here more specific questions, like: how to make a stay on top, transparent form and so on...

Answer (score 5):

[StickOut: A Desktop Sticky Notes Application in the .NET Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480731.aspx) would be a good start.